Checkbox PROP Change Then a Function
What i am trying to do is give the checkbox a function when i change the PROP of it with the Range Slider.
You Can click the checkbox and it works but not when the range slider changes the PROP
This is what i have tried...
.hotelsign {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 200px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
    }

<div class="hotelsign"></div>
    <button type="button" id="play-button">Play</button>
    <form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput1.value">
        <input type="range" id="rangeInput1" name="rangeInput1" step="20" value="0" min="0" max="100"
            oninput="updateValue1()">
    </form>
    <label class="switch" id="myform2">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>

    document.querySelector('#play-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        music.play();
    });

    const music = new Audio('https://tim-school.com/codepen/bells2/miss.mp3');
    const seeker = document.querySelector('#rangeInput1');

    music.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
        const percent = music.currentTime / music.duration * 100;
        seeker.value = percent;
        updateValue1();
    });

    seeker.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        music.currentTime = e.target.value / 100 * music.duration;
    });


    function updateValue1() {
        var rangeInput1 = document.getElementById("rangeInput1").value
        if (rangeInput1 == 0) {
            $("#myform2 :checkbox").prop("checked", true);
        }
        if (rangeInput1 == 20) {
            $("#myform2 :checkbox").prop("checked", false);
        }
        if (rangeInput1 == 40) {
            $("#myform2 :checkbox").prop("checked", true);
        }
        if (rangeInput1 == 60) {
            $("#myform2 :checkbox").prop("checked", false);
        }
        if (rangeInput1 == 80) {
            $("#myform2 :checkbox").prop("checked", true);
        }
        if (rangeInput1 == 100) {
            $("#myform2 :checkbox").prop("checked", false);
        }
    }

    // This is what i want when rangeInput1 changes the PROP
    $('#myform2 :checkbox').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(".hotelsign").css({ 'display': 'none' });
        } else {
            $(".hotelsign").css({ 'display': 'block' });
        }
    });

i'm Looking for a range slider that checks a checkbox and the function works.

Your code is not working because amount.value=rangeInput1.value initially is undefined. if you define it properly your code will work

Your code is not working because you have oninput=" amount.value=rangeInput1.value" on the form which initially is undefined, hence first-time slider drag gives you an error, and then it starts working.
In my opinion, it's not required at all, so remove it.
Also, use the || operator to combine multiple conditions into one to cut down multiple if-else statement
Now to achieve what you want create another common function where you check check-box is checked or not, and based on that do the functionality. Now call this function on range slider change as well as check-box change too
A pointer: Always use meaningful names for functions and classes.
Working snippet:


const music = new Audio('https://tim-school.com/codepen/bells2/miss.mp3');
const seeker = document.querySelector('#rangeInput1');

music.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
  const percent = music.currentTime / music.duration * 100;
  seeker.value = percent;
  updateRangeSlider();
});

seeker.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  music.currentTime = e.target.value / 100 * music.duration;
});

document.querySelector('#play-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  music.play();
});
updateRangeSlider();




function updateRangeSlider() {
  var rangeInput1 = document.getElementById("rangeInput1").value
  if (rangeInput1 == 0 || rangeInput1 == 40 || rangeInput1 == 80) {
    $("#myform2 :checkbox").prop("checked", true);
    updateAudioCss();
  }
  if (rangeInput1 == 20 || rangeInput1 == 60 || rangeInput1 == 100) {
    $("#myform2 :checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    updateAudioCss();
  }
}

// This is what i want when rangeInput1 changes the PROP
$('#myform2 :checkbox').change(function() {
  updateAudioCss();
});

function updateAudioCss() {
  if ($('#myform2 :checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $(".hotelsign").css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
  } else {
    $(".hotelsign").css({
      'display': 'block'
    });
  }
}
.hotelsign {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
<div class="hotelsign"></div>
<button type="button" id="play-button">Play</button>
<form>
  <input type="range" id="rangeInput1" name="rangeInput1" step="20" value="0" min="0" max="100" oninput="updateRangeSlider()">
</form>
<label class="switch" id="myform2">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>




I need the hotelsign div to display:none when the checkbox is checked  .. it works when you click it but not when the range slider checks it..

@timbukto I have modified my code. Please re-check
